# Knockout: Modular Views Based On Model Field

Tags: knockout.js

**Question:** Is it possible to have different views for a model based on the value it has for a field?

**Explanation:** I have a model with a *Settings* and *Type* field in it. The settings can be different settings model based on the type. I would like to switch out the view for the settings based on the value of *Type*.

I have minor experience with knockout, and would like this to scalable for many different types.

I tried using a ko.computedObservable with a switch statement to return a function() that defines the settings in it; such as:

```
self.Settings = ko.computed(function () {

    switch (self.Type()) {

        case "Type1":

            return new Type1(model.Settings);

        case "Type2":

            return new Type2(model.Settings);
    }

});
```

Type1 and Type2 are functions with the unique settings for each type of the model. *This failed miserably.*

I may just be over complicating the problem, so a second pair of eyes and any suggestions would be fantastic!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I may have time to present a full answer later if no one does in the meantime, but for now - take a look at templates, and specifically [dynamically choosing a template](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html#note-5-dynamically-choosing-which-template-is-used)

Comment: @JamesThorpe can you add your suggestion as an answer? :)

Comment: @firstdoit Done!  Meant to revisit this over the weekend...

Comment: Thanks! Just trying to get everything answered :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using [templates](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html) for your different views.  By doing so, you can then make use of the ability to [dynamically](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html#note-5-dynamically-choosing-which-template-is-used) choose which template is rendered based on a property of your viewmodel.  For example, assuming your viewmodel looks something like:

```
var vm = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.Settings = ko.computed(function () {
        switch (self.Type()) {
            case "Type1":
                return new Type1(model.Settings);

            case "Type2":
                return new Type2(model.Settings);
        }
    });

    //Based on your example computed, we'll return a different template name
    //for each object type you're returning
    self.templateName = function(t) {
        if (t instanceof Type1)
            return "template_type1";
        if (t instanceof Type2)
            return "template_type2";

        return "template_unknown";
    }
};
```

Your main view then binds to your collection as normal, but with the `template` binding making use of the function defined on your viewmodel:

```html
<div data-bind="template: { name: templateName, foreach: Settings }"></div>
```

You can then include templates in your script that bind to specific properties of each type:

```html
<script id="template_type1" type="text/html">
    <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
</script>
<script id="template_type2" type="text/html">
    <h3 data-bind="text: title"></h3>
</script>
<script id="template_unknown" type="text/html">
    <span>Unknown item type</span>
</script>
```